# error: ‘class List<RGBApixel>’ has no member named ‘curr’ Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I dont know why I'm getting this error: list.cpp:127: error: ‘class List’ has no member named ‘curr’

```
template <class T>
List<T> List<T>::mixSplit()
{
    List<T> * newList;
    class List<T>::ListNode * curr = head;

    newList->length=0;
    newList->length-3;
    newList->head = NULL;
    newList->tail=NULL;

    for (int count=0;count<1;count++)
        newList->curr=newList->curr->next;

    newList->head=newList->curr;
    newList->tail=tail;

    tail=newList->curr->prev;
    tail->next=NULL;

    newList->head->prev=NULL;
    newList->tail->next=NULL;

    return newList;
}
```

The error is occuring at

```
newList->curr=newList->curr->next;
```

When I do this:

```
    class List<T>::ListNode * curr = head;
```

Shouldn't that allow for `curr` to be the head of `newList`?

Edit: 
Here is the class definition:

```
template <class T>
class List
{
private:
class ListNode
{
    public:
    // constructors; implemented in list_given.cpp
    ListNode();
    ListNode(T const & ndata);

    // member variables
    ListNode * next;
    ListNode * prev;
    const T data; // const because we do not want to modify node's data
};
```

Comment: How about posting the definition of the class List?

Comment: You need to post the error. From the given code, it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `typename` as instead of `class`:

```
typename List<T>::ListNode * curr = head; //correct
//class List<T>::ListNode * curr = head; //incorrect
```

It is one example where you cannot use `class` in place of `typename`.

> error: **list.cpp**:127: error: ‘class List’ has no member named ‘curr’

From the error, it is clear that the definition of the template is in `.cpp` file.  That is another reason of the problem. You cannot provide the definition of template in another file. The declaration and definition should be in the same file. So move all the definition to the header file.

Comment: Im not sure if thats the issue earlier in the code I was able to use the pointer curr but for some reason here when I try newList isn't getting the member curr. I just want to assign a pointer to the head of the new list.

Comment: You are right that this is one example where `class` cannot replace `typename`. However for user defined classes, [class can replace typename](http://ideone.com/Qqess). Also, if `typename` was an issue then line of error would be different.

Comment: @user949358: Why don't you post the code of `List<T>`? And also let us know the headers and source file.

Comment: @Nawaz Added the class definition I'm just confused on how I can assign a pointer to the head of the newList

Comment: @user949358: I don't see any member `curr` in the definition. Why don't you see what you've posted, and what members you're trying to access?

Answer (score 0):

The class `List` doesn't have a member `curr`, that's what the error says. I'm pretty sure that the class does indeed not have that member.

The fact that there's another variable in a different scope with the same name - is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no member like, `curr` inside `List<T>`! You misunderstood that, `curr` is a member of `List<T>::ListNode`!!.

Just declaring a `class` inside `class` doesn't mean that all the inner class members delegated to outer class too and vice verse. You need to have `ListNode* curr;` inside `List<T>` to accomplish this.

After solving compiler errors you will end up solving **runtime errors** because there are several other problems with your class. For example,

```
List<T> * newList;  // dangling/uninitialized pointer
class List<T>::ListNode * curr = head;  // curr is unused and pointing to something unknown
```

You must initialize `newList = new List<T>;` to use the pointer. Or you can declare an automatic object as `List<T> newList;`.